# zlib.dll unable to add reference

Tags: c#, dll, reference

I am working in VS 2012 C# and trying to add reference to zlib.dll, which I downloaded from [ZLIB web-site](http://www.zlib.net/). I am getting the following error message while trying to add reference:

> A reference to 'C:\CTS\T4ClientSim\bin\zlib1.dll' could
>   not be added. Please make sure that file is accessible, and that is
>   a valid assembly or COM component.

I tried to launch VS as administrator, but it did not help.

Any help?

Comment: zlib looks like a native library and not a .net library...what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, I am try to use CTS T4 API. This is API to pull stock market quotes and more, developed by CTS. I am trying to instantiate an object and it is asking for zlib reference.  There is zlib.dll supplied with CTS T4 API, but it generates the same error. I am also reading [link](http://www.componentace.com/.NET_zip_component_zipforge.htm)

Comment: Again...its a native dll. You can't use it with .net, you can try to use C++/CLR to code a P/Invoke interop layer, but if you could do that you would know what is going wrong.

Comment: On same site there are several links to dotnet wrappers for the native dll